# Custom Annotation implementation Hibernate not getting called

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I need to invoke custom annotation implementation , But my implementation is not getting called. 
In the

below code snippet ,I have a Profile Object with two fields (id , content). Content field accept 
a string and

need to change the content at runtime via a custom annotation.

My domain object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile", catalog = "db")
public class Profile implements java.io.Serializable{

private Integer profileId;
@ProcessContent(convertor = ProcessContent.class)
private String  content;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "PROFILE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)

public Integer getProfileId() {
    return profileId;
}
public void setProfileId(Integer profileId) {
    this.profileId = profileId;
}

@Column(name = "CONTENT", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 255)
public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}
```

}

My custom annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Documented
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ProcessContent {

     @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class<? extends Object> convertor() default DefaultFieldValueConvertor.class;
}
```

Sample Annotation implementation. (Please note that this is a sample and complex logic comes here)

```
public class DefaultFieldValueConvertor {

    public Object convert(Object value) {
        return (value + "Processed");
    }


}
```

Tester

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        profile.setContent("OOOOOOOOOPSSSSSSSSS");
        session.save(profile);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
    }
```

Question - > I can see the passing string getting save in DB instead the one processed via my annotation implementation.

Comment: why do you expect the annotation to be called? There is nothing in the code you posted to trigger it.

Comment: My actual scenario is bit complex. I need to keep my question simple.  I need to have a annotation which is generic for all the domain objects and trigger it just  before the save. But I need the original value before process for other work which i do in hibernate interceptor level. My question is why the implementation defined in DefaultFieldValueConvertor  is not getting called ?

Comment: What I mean is - what mechanism is supposed to trigger the annotation processing? Why do you expect JPA to do it on save, instead of say, update or load? JPA does not process random annotations - it has a set it looks for and leaves all others be.

Comment: I was under the impression that JPA will process the custom annotation and it's implementation. In that case I have to write code that looks for their presence and takes action. I can look for annotation via reflection. and then call for necessary actions.

Comment: Perhaps using JPA lifecycle listeners is a more appropriate option for you. Before I post it as an answer I would like to reiterate your issue in order to see whether I understand it correctly: When storing/loading/merging etc. an entity instance, you want to change certain attributes.

Comment: Yes ,my decision to use listeners and hibernate interceptors to change the content in the way i want. Then i want to save this content in zip format. i do not like to zip / unzip in object setters and getters. Because that is what returns to listeners and interceptors. To make it zip and unzip i am planning to use Hibernate custom type def

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute code on JPA lifecycle events like loading, merging, refreshing etc, you can use JPA [lifecycle listeners](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html). You can define listener callback methods inside your entity or in an own class. If you use the callback in a single entity type, listener methods is the easy way. Use listener classes when you need a certain type of operation to be performed on different entity types.

If you want to manipulate data before storing it, you can combine the [@PreUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PreUpdate.html) and the [@PrePersist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html) callbacks.

```
@PreUpdate
@PrePersist
public void convert() {
   content += "Processed";
}
```

Comment: Hi, this method called everytime when I submit the entity, so how it is attached with the custome annotation ? Can you provide me a good example or link to learn custom annotation implementation with hibernate.

Comment: My scenario of using custom annotation is to encrypt and decrypt a string using just an annotation. What should I do to perform this ?  Any help would we appreciate. please guide me.

Comment: I am not sure that we are on the same page here. In my answer and the comments I am explaining how JPA does **not** support custom annotations. Lifecycle listener and callback annotations is all you can use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. So I can not use custom annotation with jpa. Is there any other way to perform this without jpa ? What if I use mongo ?