# Custom annotation with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am new to custom annotation binding and hibernate.

> I am developing a custom annotation which encrypt and decrypt a string
>   in a hibernate entity.

I am not understanding the exact procedure to do this. I try this based on information I found, but my code is not work.

> I found a similar question
>   [Custom Annotation implementation Hibernate not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524535/custom-annotation-implementation-hibernate-not-getting-called][1])

but my requirement is bit different and clear. Need some guidance.

My entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="demo")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Demo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String somethingPublic;

    @EncryptDemo(convertor = EncryptDemo.class)
    private String somethingPrivate;

   //getter setter

}
```

my custome annotation.

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EncryptDemo {

     Class<? extends Object> convertor() default PrivateEncryptor.class;

}
```

my PrivateEncryptor class

```
public Object encrypt(Object encryptedString) {
       //encrypt code.
       return encryptedString;
    }
```

**My entity is store in database but not processed via annotation implementation.**

I try this and my string encrypted,

```
    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void convert() {
        //my encrypt code
    }
```

however this is not associated with my custom annotation. I am stuck at this position. Please give me some link or example to create custom annotation with hibernate. Any help will be appreciate. Please guide me toward this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got one answer from  the link I attached in question is that Hibernate does not support custom annotation. Can we use this with mongodb ? Is there any other way to perform this ?

Comment: How should Hibernate know what you custom annotation is for? Annotations are nothing specific to Hibernate - every java class can inspect them. You will have to write your own code that evaluates your annotation.

Comment: Hi Tobias, Thanks for comment, now in which direction should I start work to full fill my requirement. I want to store my encrypted field directly to database. I am confused with this. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: May be you should rewrite your whole query to "How can I store and load an encrypted value" and describe what you want to do. I think that the most obvious solutions are without any custom annotation - so your question is misleading.

Comment: So to write custom annotation for encryption does not make sense. Let me rewrite my query. Thanks.